# C# While Loop only works with Messagebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My While loop only works if i put a MessageBox in it. Ever time i press OK the Variable ValueT1-6 get written in the textBoxes (as they should).
If i delete the MessageBox the programm just doesn't work anymore and nothing gets written in the textBoxes. I really don't know what the problem is.

My Code:

```
          public void Main()  //Main-Programm
    {
        while (x == 1)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("here");
            //Open the first found LabJack U6.
            u6 = new U6(LJUD.CONNECTION.USB, "0", true); // Connection through USB

            LJUD.eAIN(u6.ljhandle, 0, 199, ref ValueT1, -1, -1, -1, binary);    //Wert von Labjack einlesen & auf Variable schreiben
            textBox1.Text = ValueT1 * 15 + " °C   ";

            LJUD.eAIN(u6.ljhandle, 1, 199, ref ValueT2, -1, -1, -1, binary);    //Wert von Labjack einlesen & auf Variable schreiben
            textBox2.Text = ValueT2 * 15 + " °C   ";

            LJUD.eAIN(u6.ljhandle, 2, 199, ref ValueT3, -1, -1, -1, binary);    //Wert von Labjack einlesen & auf Variable schreiben
            textBox3.Text = ValueT3 * 15 + " °C   ";

            LJUD.eAIN(u6.ljhandle, 3, 199, ref ValueT4, -1, -1, -1, binary);    //Wert von Labjack einlesen & auf Variable schreiben
            textBox4.Text = ValueT4 * 15 + " °C   ";

            LJUD.eAIN(u6.ljhandle, 4, 199, ref ValueT5, -1, -1, -1, binary);    //Wert von Labjack einlesen & auf Variable schreiben
            textBox5.Text = ValueT5 * 15 + " °C   ";

            LJUD.eAIN(u6.ljhandle, 5, 199, ref ValueT6, -1, -1, -1, binary);    //Wert von Labjack einlesen & auf Variable schreiben
            textBox6.Text = ValueT6 * 15 + " °C   ";

        }
    }
```

I don't want the MessageBox in my final code. it was just for testing.

Comment: The reason for this is how winforms is made. It uses messages, and every change you make to the content of a textbox puts a message in a queue, to be processed by the message pump. However, the message pump is currently waiting for your while-loop to return, so it can continue pumping messages. If you show a messagebox, a secondary message pump will be started which will process messages while the messagebox is visible. Basically, you need to fix your code so you're not blocking the message pump. Look into using a timer instead of a while-loop.

Comment: What kind of application is this (Console, Windows Forms, etc.)?  What does "only works" mean?  Have you stepped through in a debugger?  As @LasseV.Karlsen points out, if you are in a framework like Windows Forms, then you need to give the message loop a chance to pump messages.  However, since your method is named `Main` I'm a little confused

Comment: You can enforce displaying the new data with a control.Refresh(); but this is not a recommended way. If the updates are meant to work like an animation use a Timer. Note that the user will need at least some time to watch the data..